# auto_explain does not log

Tags: postgresql, logs

looks like i do it wrong. I turned auto_explain on with adding next valued to postgresql.conf:

```
shared_preload_libraries = 'pg_stat_statements,pg_wait_sampling,pg_stat_kcache,auto_explain'
auto_explain.log_min_duration = '3s'
```

in my monitoring I can see long running queries that exceeded limit of 3s and successfully finished.

'values' here says how long query lasted:
[image: from my grafana monitoring]

But when I look into my log 'postgresql-Mon.log' (and next days) there is nothing about those queries. Only a few strings about modules during database startup process.

Am I missing something?

Comment: What info is that png supposed to be conveying?

Comment: oh, yes, thanks, the value is the time in seconds for how long query lasted.

Comment: Did you restart the server?  Those changes will not take effect until a restart (I don't think a reload is sufficient).

Comment: Yes I did. Actually super heavy queries appeared there, so, will focus on them, so hope decreasing of auto_explain.log_min_duration will help to see more queries :)

Answer (score 0):

Look over the documentation regarding this extension

pg_stat_statements  does not persist between restarts...
[pg_stat_statements](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/pgstatstatements.html)

pg_stat_statements_reset() will clear all data